# Javascript library event not working with lists of elements

Tags: javascript

I am working an a javacript library for events. Here is some of the libraries code:

```
(function(){
        var elem,
            int,
            Jist = function(s){
                return new Jist.fn.init(s);
            };
        Jist.fn = Jist.prototype ={
            init : function(s){
                if(!s){
                    return this;
                }
                else{
                    this.length = 1;
                    if (typeof s === "object"){
                        this[0] = s;
                    }
                    else if(typeof s === "string"){
                        var obj;
                        obj = document.querySelectorAll(s);
                        this[0] = obj;
                        elem = this[0];
                    }
                    return this;
                }
            }
        }
        Jist.fn.init.prototype = Jist.fn;
        Jist.fn.init.prototype = {
            print : function(txt){
                for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
                    elem[i].innerHTML = txt;
                }
            },
            click : function(callback){
            for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++) {
                elem[i].addEventListener("click",callback,false);
            }
        },  
        };
        window.Jist = window.jist = window.Jis = window.jis = window.Jit = window.jit = window._ = Jist;
})();
```

Here is what I have in my webpage to test it out:

```
<input type="button" id="inpt" value="click"></input>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
<script>
jist("#inpt").click(function(){
    jist(".test").print("hello world");
    window.setTimeout(function(){jist(".test").print("nata");},2000);
});
</script>
```

When I click the button, it doesn't even print the text to one of the divs, it doesn't do anything. When I check the console there is a "type" error in the `.click` function of the library. Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What "*"type" error*" and where?

Comment: WTH is your `elem` variable static, instead of bound to the single instances? Also, what is it supposed to contain?

Comment: @Bergi Chrome says there is a type error in my library on the `.click` protptype function.

Comment: @Bergi The `elem` element is supposed to be the object.

Comment: @CodeApprentice So when you call jist() a second time it wipes away the elem from the first call? I doubt you wanted that.

Comment: @epascarello hmm, how do I fix that?

Comment: @epascarello Never mind, I fixed it! By the way, it is on github.

Comment: @Bergi Never mind, I fixed it! By the way, it is on github.